# Unflatten a tensor back to an image

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am working on GANs and I want to visualize the image formed.

For this, I was trying

```
def show_images(image_tensor, num_images=9, size=(1, 28, 28)):
    image_unflat = image_tensor.detach().cpu.view(-1, *size)
    image_grid = make_grid(image_unflat[:num_images], nrow=3)
    plt.imshow(image_grid.permute(1, 2, 0).squeeze())
    plt.show()
```

but when I am trying to `show_image(some_tensor)`, I am getting an error as

```
image_unflat = image_tensor.detach().cpu.view(-1, *size)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'view'
```

Here, the size of some_tensor is N x 784.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`cpu()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.cpu) before broadcasting with `view`.

```
image_unflat = image_tensor.detach().cpu().view(-1, *size)
```